# Масштабирование wpf в elementhost c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Создаю приложение **winforms**.
Есть elementhost с wpf.

***Вопрос:*** как масштабировать wpf в elementhost?
Просто метод **Scale()** elementhost не работает выдает ошибку

*Буду признателен за какой-то нормальный ответ!* *Долго не могу найти как решить данную проблему.*

**Заранее спасибо!**

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с тем, как должен выглядеть [mcve].

Comment: Текст сообщения об ошибки имеет смысл добавить в текст вопроса. И полезно глянуть - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve